# Viewing history for Maintenance Plan causing out of memory exception

Tags: sql, maintenance, ssms

I am trying to view history for a maintenance plan but keep getting an out of memory exception. It seems that the problem is that SSMS can't access memory beyond the ~3gb range. I've tried to find an x64 version of SSMS to no avail. I've tried increasing the memory a process can use with BCDEDIT, but that did not work either. I've tried to filter the results so that I'm only viewing a portion of the log, but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know if/when there will be an x64 version of SSMS and/or how to view history for a maintenance plan some other way? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no 32bit version of SSMS.  This is because SSMS is built on Visual Studio and Visual Studio is only available as a 32bit app.  I've got the most recent SQL Server 2012 public build installed and it is still a 32bit app.  I wouldn't expect a 64bit build of SSMS until SQL 2012 R2 or whatever it's called.